# Multiply before normalization

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Let vector `v` close to zero like `{7.000e-07, 5.000e-06, 4.000e-07}`. Is it good idea to multiply by, say, 1024, before normalization? Seems like such close values work good on PC where double is 80 bit internally and bad on ARM FPU.

Comment: "Normalization" is a rather broad concept - you may need to give a little more context (i.e. what is your problem domain - audio, video or other signal processing, finite element modelling, ...?) to get useful answers. Are you "normalizing" to `+/- 1e-4` or `+/- 1` or `+/- 1e6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as none of the intermediate results in the computation you want to do underflow (that is, as long as they do not get close to 1E-308 in `double`, 1E-38 in `float`), it brings nothing to multiply by 1024.

It would not lose anything to multiply by 1024 (except if it causes overflow), but other factors (say, 1000) would cause a loss of precision, too.